# google style autocomplete with arrow keys

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrow-keys

i created a simple search engine that displays mysql database results using the php "LIKE" function (code below).  everything works fine.  i would just like to make it so that when the user starts typing he/she can use the arrow keys to scroll down and press enter on an item just like google.  thanks. my code:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name='search' id="searchbooks" onkeyup='getbooks(this.value);'       value="search" onblur="setTimeout('removedrop()', 80);">

<div id='drop'></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function getbooks(value){
    if (value!=""){



    $.post('getbooks.php', {book: value},
        function (data) {
            $('#drop').html(data);
            doCSS();                
        });

        }
        else {

        $('#drop').html("");
        undoCSS();
        }
```

}
getbooks.php file:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

$book=mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_POST['book']));

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE title LIKE '$book%'");


while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$title=$row['title'];
$id=$row['id'];


echo "<div id='link'><a href='index.php?id=$id' id='words'>". $row['title'] ."</a></div>";

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the [jQuery autocomplete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)? It's made for exactly this use case.

[image]

Comment: Um. I'm not sure how my significant other feels about that `:P`

Comment: @matt i just looked through those files.  this seems very complicated for such a small adjustment.  is there another way to do this using the code i already have

Comment: My apologies, I actually linked to a really old version. I updated the link (and image) in my answer. Hopefully you'll find that the up-to-date autocomplete is much simpler to use.

Comment: @matt is there a way to make the drop down items links?  and also a way to remove the name of the hover from the textbox when the user scrolls over it.